# How to select specific details from a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

**I want to create a new object in Python that corresponds to the first and last names of the female members in the data frame.**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Index = np.array(['B1','L1','T1','G1','L2'])
Name =  pd.Series(['Bob','Linda','Tina','Gene','Louise'] , index = Index )
Gender = pd.Series(['Male','Female','Female','Male','Female'] , index = Index )
Age = pd.Series([46,42,13,11,9] , index = Index )
Occupation = pd.Series(['Chef','Restaurateur','Student','Student','Student'] , index = Index )
Rating = pd.Series([7,6,9,9,8] , index = Index )

burger = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(Name=Name,Gender=Gender,Age=Age,Occupation=Occupation,Rating=Rating))
burger
```

[image: Picture of Data]

I know that the following code is how to select certain things from a series, but I am unsure how to do so when it comes to a data frame.

```
burger.loc[]
burger.iloc[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,output is a data frame

```
df = burger[burger.Gender=="Female"][["Name"]]
```

If you need a series as output

```
df = burger[burger.Gender=="Female"]["Name"]
```

Comment: If I wanted to go by Gender and Age, would that be doable?

Comment: you can use like this `burger[(burger.Gender=="Female") & (burger.Age ==12) ]["Name"]`

Comment: Sorry, one more question. When I am using this code, `df = burger[burger.Gender=="Female"][["Name"]]` is it possible to also include Occupation with the Name?

Comment: yes if you need  multiple columns `df = burger[burger.Gender=="Female"][["Name","Occupation"]]`

Comment: Ooh! Thank you, I was forgetting the comma.